# How can I ADD own list of coupons programmatically in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to add my own coupons to salerule, but all the examples I found were created by magento generator.

```
// Get the rule in question
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(21); //21 = ID of coupon in question

// Define a coupon code generator model instance
// Look at Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon_Massgenerator for options
$generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon_massgenerator');

$parameters = array(
    'count'=>5,
    'format'=>'alphanumeric',
    'dash_every_x_characters'=>4,
    'prefix'=>'ABCD-EFGH-',
    'suffix'=>'-WXYZ',
    'length'=>8
);

if( !empty($parameters['format']) ){
  switch( strtolower($parameters['format']) ){
    case 'alphanumeric':
    case 'alphanum':
      $generator->setFormat( Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC );
      break;
    case 'alphabetical':
    case 'alpha':
      $generator->setFormat( Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHABETICAL );
      break;
    case 'numeric':
    case 'num':
      $generator->setFormat( Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_NUMERIC );
      break;
  }
}

$generator->setDash( !empty($parameters['dash_every_x_characters'])? (int) $parameters['dash_every_x_characters'] : 0);
$generator->setLength( !empty($parameters['length'])? (int) $parameters['length'] : 6);
$generator->setPrefix( !empty($parameters['prefix'])? $parameters['prefix'] : '');
$generator->setSuffix( !empty($parameters['suffix'])? $parameters['suffix'] : '');

// Set the generator, and coupon type so it's able to generate
$rule->setCouponCodeGenerator($generator);
$rule->setCouponType( Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_AUTO );

// Get as many coupons as you required
$count = !empty($parameters['count'])? (int) $parameters['count'] : 1;
$codes = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ){
  $coupon = $rule->acquireCoupon();
  $code = $coupon->getCode();
  $codes[] = $code;
}
return $codes;
```

It's fine, but this genereted codes, and I have a list of codes and must put in into salerules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert custom coupons in a direct sql query:

```
// Get the rule in question
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(21);

//preconfigure data
$primary = $rule->getPrimaryCoupon();
$data = array(
    $rule->getId(), 
   '', 
   intVal($primary->getUsageLimit()), 
   intVal($primary->getUsagePerCustomer()), 
   $primary->getExpirationDate(),
);   

$table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('salesrule/coupon');
//preconfig sql
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `$table` (`rule_id`, `code`, `usage_limit`, `usage_per_customer`, `expiration_date`) VALUES "; 

//coupons variable contain all needed coupon codes in array like
//$coupons = array('mycustomcoupon1','mycustomcoupon2');
$data[1] =  "'" . implode(',', $coupons) . "'";

//adding coupons string to preconfigured sql
$sql .= '(' . implode(',', $data) . '),';   

//USE YOUR COMPANYNAME_MODULENAME from config.xml
$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('COMPANYNAME_MODULENAME');        
//insert coupons
$db->raw_query(substr($sql, 0, -1));
```